# How to "lightbox" a div non clickable for disapear ? [Without JS]

Tags: html, css

I want my score's div beeing a lightbox when cliking on that link :

```
<a href="#test">TEST</a>
```

But we don't want to make it disapear by clicking on the div, **JUST** only on the black background !

here are my tries :

```
<a id="test" href="#">
  <div id="details">
    many scores ! : <br>
    test n°1 : 16/20<br>
    test n°2 : 11/20<br>
    test n°3 : 17/20<br>
    test n°4 : 14/20<br>
    test n°5 : 15/20<br>
  </div>
</a>
```

But as you can see in this fiddle we can click on the lightbox in order to make it disapear ... : http://jsfiddle.net/apr4Ln3j/

and without JS by the way ... Which sadly i'm not allowed to use --'

Comment: Not sure to understdang what you need to

Comment: I believe what he's referring to is typically known as a lightbox... and created with javascript

Comment: Yeah ! Didn't know it was that name ^^

Comment: How can you trigger things without JS? You can do hovers via CSS, but that won't be enough here, I'm afraid.

Comment: with the :target selector ! check this : http://schier.co/post/creating-pure-css-lightboxes-with-the-:target-selector#_

But I want the div non-clikable !

Comment: jsfrocha's answer is a way, but if you plan to extend that functionality any further... well, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

On the example you provided clicking both the background or the image box when opened closes it.

However, you could try messing around with the `pointer-events` [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcgvmmgh/)

I've modified your Fiddle to make the box clickable, and the background not clickable using this property. I know you want the opposite, but maybe now you can get there yourself - I'm just guiding to a possible path.

Comment: well i added the 
    `pointer-events: none;` to #test but we can still click and furthemore i saw that my div is also with an opacity of 0.8 why ? ...

Comment: Sorry but the question is about to close the lightbox only at clicking the black overlay.

Comment: I am aware of the question. I am also not a fan of providing answers on a silver platter. I just gave the tools with which the OP can be able to solve his problem. I've shown an example of the opposite of what he wants, as a clue.

Comment: well i put none for the div but still make the div disapear because of inheritance maybe ? One more hint ? ^^ 

And well my opacity of the div is still to 0.8 but in CSS i rewrite the div opacity to 1 ... Why it don't do what i want ? :P

Comment: try using the `:target` selector in conjunction with `pointer-events` and edit the question with what you tried